# Can I pay for a realm and my friend can download his world into it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

We are trying to play on a friends world when he is not able to play often ... I am happy to pay the monthly fee but don’t want to have his friend control the world if he decides to change things

Comment: So you want a separate Realm, but with the same world/save file as your friend's? If that is what you mean, then you can get your friend to install a local backup of his Realm and send it to you, which you can then restore into your Realm.

Comment: Yes thank you :) they are both on Xbox is that possible

Comment: Does it need to e in a realm first ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that what you want is to transfer a world from your friend's console to your console. I'm guessing your friend has a Realm. If you want to play multiplayer with your friends, but you want to control the world, then this world has to be reuploaded into your own Realm. Or you could start an LAN server and port forward it, instructions which can be found online.

Since you're both using Xbox and Bedrock, yes, you do need to use Realms to transfer the world from his device to yours. What you need to do is to log into your friend's Xbox live account - both your devices must be logged into the SAME Xbox Live account.

Then follow the following steps:

From the first device (your friend's), please do the following:

1. Select the pen icon next to your Realm from the Realms list
2. Select "Replace World" and confirm
3. Choose the world you would like to transfer
4. Wait for the upload and select "Let's go!"

Access Minecraft from the second device (your Xbox) and do the following:

1. Select the pen icon next to your Realm from the Realms list
2. Select "Download World"
3. Wait for the download and select "Let's go!"

I have not used an Xbox before, but I'm guessing that even if you do log out of your Xbox Live account, your local world files will remain. Now your world has been transferred.

With the world you now have, you can upload it into a Realm of your own or start a LAN server in order to play it with your friends.

Source: [Minecraft Help article](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034754892)